# Compare results of 2 split strings?

Tags: c#, string, split, string-comparison

I have two string inputs with that have been split so each item is distinguishable from the other (these items are product properties such as length, weight, finish, stain color, etc.). One string has the original values for the product while the other has the new values (whatever they may be--users can edit whichever product values they want).

Right now, I have the split strings producing the info that I want but I am not sure how to compare the results to each other since the individual product values are inside foreach loops.

This is what I have:

```
 //checks to see which attributes have been changed/edited for the product
protected bool ifAttrChanged(string oldItm, string newItm)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    //get the original attributes of the product
    string[] oldItms = oldItm.Split(',');
    foreach (string oItm in oldItms)
    {
        if (oItm != "")
        {
            string[] oldThings = oItm.Split(',');
            string oldies = oldThings.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
    }

    //get whatever new values have been entered for the product
    string[] newItms = newItm.Split(',');
    foreach (string nItm in newItms)
    {
        if (nItm != "")
        {
            string[] newThings = nItm.Split(',');
            string newbies = newThings.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
    }
    if (newItms.ToString().Equals(oldItms.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        retVal = false;
        Label3.Text += retVal.ToString() + "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = true;
        Label3.Text += retVal.ToString() + "<br />";
    }
     return retVal;
}
```

I would really like to compare the oldies string variable with the newbies string variable (weird names but I am not concerned about that) but they are each in their own foreach statement and I cannot access them elsewhere. How can I compare the old and new values of the two split strings successfully so I can obtain which values were changed and which values remained the same?

Comment: Use a simple `for` and use the index for both arrays?

Comment: You can use a tradition for loop to get through the both arrays at the same time and compare the values.

Comment: Where are you wanting output? Do you want the method to return a result or are you wanting the output written to your **Label** `Label3` control?

Comment: You can avoid the need for the `if (oItm != "")` by using the [String.Split Method (Char(), StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all the strings splittend and stored in arrays (oldItems and newItems), and using System.Linq.

Try this:

```
var changedResults = newItems.Where(x => !oldItems.Any(y => x == y));
```

With this you will get a IEnumerable with all the string in newItems which no appear in oldItems array.
If you want to convert this to a list or something, add this:

```
var changedResults = newItems.Where(x => !oldItems.Any(y => x == y)).ToList();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm.... well, she appears to be struggling with the basics, and you gave her some Linq. LOL

Comment: hahaha Linq is not so complicated :P and.. it worth ;) don´t you think so? heheh

Comment: Np ;) I am glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

What is a "change"?  Addition?  Deletion?  Modification?

If only addition, Oscar's method works.  This is the same thing (set difference) but a little more concise:

```
var changedResults = newItems.Except(oldItems)
```

However, if a deletion is a "change" as well, you would need to consider it from both sides.

```
var changedResults = newItems.Except(oldItems).Union(oldItems.Except(newItems));
```

Since the sets are of only strings, there is no notion of modification.